# How to make 2 Dropdown options once checked link to a website page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hope someone can help with what I'm trying to do.
The code that is here I have it on my test page http://glysomed.bydecosta.com/test1.php

I need to be able to do the following:

Once users click for eg: 
I am: "Someone who works with my hands" from Dropdown 1
and I need: "UV Protection" from Dropdown 2
Once the user clicks on Go it needs to take the user to a page: 
http://glysomed.bydecosta.com/portfolio-item/hand-cream-frag-free/

Or:
Once a user clicks for eg:
I am: "Someone who works with my feet" from Dropdown 1
and I need: "Skin Relief" from Dropdown 2
Once the user clicks Go it needs to take the user to a page:
http://glysomed.bydecosta.com/portfolio-item/foot-balm/

Hope someone can help.

Thanks,
Marcelo

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $( ".go-btn" ).click(function() {
        // Grab text from select boxes
        var firstSelection = $( "#selection1 option:selected" ).text();
        var secondSelection = $( "#selection2 option:selected" ).text();

        // Set URL, change as necessary
        var url = "http://www.example.com/" + firstSelection + "/" + secondSelection;

        // Redirect
        window.location.href = url;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selCont">
  
  <h2>Me Time</h2>

I Am:
  <select id="select1">
   <option value=" " selected="selected">- Select -</option>
    <option value="1">Someone who works with my hands</option>
    <option value="2">Someone who works wit my feet</option>
    <option value="3">Someone who works with my body</option>
  </select>

and I need:
  <select id="select2">
    <option value=" " selected="selected">- Select -</option>
    <option value="1">UV Protection</option>
    <option value="2">Acne</option>
    <option value="3">Dry Skin</option>
    <option value="4">Eczema</option>
    <option value="5">Itchy Relief</option>
    <option value="6">Redness</option>
    <option value="7">Sensitive Skin</option>
  </select>

  <button class="go-btn" type="submit">Go</button>
  
</div>
<div id="selected"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The id's in the selectors or the markup will need to be updated to match eachother on top of the code below. I assumed you will have multiple combinations of url's to build so you can add extra case statements below to handle whichever are needed:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $( ".go-btn" ).click(function() {
        var firstSelection = $( "#selection1 option:selected" ).val();
        var firstPart;
        switch(firstSelection) {
            case '1':
            case '2':
             firstPart = 'portfolio-item';
             break;
            default:
             firstPart = '';
             break;
        }

        var secondSelection = $( "#selection2 option:selected" ).val();
        var secondPart;
        switch(secondSelection) {
            case '1':    
             secondPart = 'hand-cream-frag-free';
             break;
            case '2':
             secondPart = 'foot-balm';
             break;
            default:
             secondPart = '';
             break;
        }

        var url = "http://glysomed.bydecosta.com/" + firstPart + "/" + secondPart;

        // Redirect
        window.location.href = url;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the easiest way to solve this problem would be to create a 2-dimensional array where you save the path which you wanna redirect the people to:

```
var link = [
    []
];
link[1] = [];
link[2] = [];
link[3] = [];
```

then apply the strings of your required path to the 2D array according to the values of your options in `select1` and `select2`

```
link[1][1] = "hand-cream-frag-free";
link[2][7] = "foot-balm";
/* ... and so on*/
```

finally in your variable `url` just concatenate your domain string with the string that's in your 2D array at this place. also fix the ids in your javascript to "`#select1`" and "`#select2`" as these are the ids you used in your html. plus, i also fixed a typo, you used `window.location.ref` instead of `window.location.href`:

```
$(".go-btn").click(function () {
    // Grab text from select boxes
    var firstSelection = $("#select1").val();
    var secondSelection = $("#select2").val();

    // Set URL, change as necessary
    var url = "http://glysomed.bydecosta.com/portfolio-item/" + link[firstSelection][secondSelection] + "/";

    // Redirect
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

working **JSFiddle**: 
http://jsfiddle.net/northkildonan/6Lrzgffs/1/